# Calculate the transfer function

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function

I have a question about this circuit. What is the transfer function for this circuit?

[image]

Comment: Isn't this so related to the earlier question you asked that it shouldn't realistically be a separate question. Anyway, when the pot is half way and, assuming R4 is present for controlling DC, the transfer function is -1.

Answer (score 1):

General formula for the transfer function of this opamp topology is

$$
H(s) = -\dfrac{Z_f(s)}{Z_i(s)}.
$$

Where, \$Z_f(s)\$ is the total impedance of feedback, and \$Z_i(s)\$ is the total impedance at the input side.

In our case,

$$
H(s) = -\dfrac{Z_f(s)}{Z_i(s)} = - \dfrac{R_2 + \dfrac{1}{C_2s} + R_{3f}}{R_1 + \dfrac{1}{C_1s} + R_{3i}} = - \dfrac{C_2s\left((R_1 + R_{3i})C_1s + 1\right)}{C_1s\left((R_2 + R_{3f})C_2s + 1\right)}.
$$

Where, \$R_{3i}\$ is the left/input side of the \$R_{3}\$ resistor, and \$R_{3f}\$ is the right/feedback side of it.

Comment: What about R4? What does that dashed lines mean'Unconnected'?